# How to calculate student score rank in scala?

Tags: scala, rank

In my issue, every student has a class, and every subject has a score for each student. 
Now I want to get all students' rank in school, rank in class for every subject and total score.
The student score data is like this:

```
userName class subject score
Mike     1     math    100
Jack     1     math    100
Jone     1     math    90
Helan    2     math    95
Mike     1     physics 100
```

and the expected result is

```
userName  mathRank mathRank(class) physicsRank physicsRank(class) sumRank sumRank(class)
Mike      1        1               1           1                   1  1
Jack      1        1       
John      4        3       
Hellan    3        1
```

I've written some code, my code below

```
  case class UserScore(userName:String,stuClass:Int,subject:String,score:Double)
  val userScores :Array[UserScore] = Array[UserScore](
  UserScore("Mike", 1, "math", 100D),
  UserScore("Jack", 1, "math", 100D),
  UserScore("Jone", 1, "math", 90D),
  UserScore("Helan", 2, "math", 95D),
  UserScore("Mike", 1, "physics", 95D))
//calculate school rank
  val subjectID2SchoolRanks = userScores.sortBy(_.score).reverse.groupBy(_.subject).map({
  case(subjectID, subjectUserScores)=>{
    var i:Int = 0
    subjectID->subjectUserScores.foldLeft(List[(UserScore,Int)]()){
      (userScoreRanks,userScore)=>{
         i= i+1
         if(userScoreRanks.nonEmpty&& userScoreRanks.last._1.score==userScore.score){
           userScoreRanks:+(userScore,userScoreRanks.last._2)
         }else {
           userScoreRanks:+(userScore,i)
         }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

but maybe not efficient and not elegant, can any one give me some suggestion, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have code that runs, and produces output, and you would like suggestions to improve it, post it, along with some sample input, over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). What you've posted here does not compile, but you haven't asked about compilation errors so I have to assume you haven't posted the complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gets the same results as yours but without the use of a mutable variable.

```
val subjectID2SchoolRanks = 
    userScores.groupBy(_.subject)
              .mapValues(_.sortWith(_.score >= _.score)
                          .zipWithIndex
                          .foldLeft((List[(UserScore,Int)](),-1.0,-1)){
                            case ((acc,pScore,pRank),(us,rank)) =>
                              if (pScore == us.score)
                                ((us,pRank)::acc, pScore, pRank)
                              else
                                ((us,rank+1)::acc, us.score, rank+1)
                          }._1.reverse)
```

I used many of the same steps but not always in the same order. `zipWithIndex` is used to establish the initial rankings and then `foldLeft` makes the necessary adjustments. Appending to a `List` is a rather inefficient operation. It's usually better to build the `List` by pre-pending to it and then `reverse` after it's built.